# Require password instead of pin for admin

Tags: windows-10, passwords, administrator, pin, user-management

Me and my family share a computer and they need to be able to login to my account (with a pin). I was wondering if I could require a password for admin privileges instead of an option to enter a pin. I use windows 10 home.  Thanks in advance!

Edit: the admin account is connected with my Microsoft account. I have windows version `1909` build number `18363.836`

Comment: Please edit your question to indicate if this Administrator account is connected to a Microsoft Account.  We also need to know which version of Windows 10 you are using.

Comment: By version do you mean version number or window home/pro

Comment: Home or Professional is the edition.  We require the build number.

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: For each account, you can remove the PIN and then (after log off an log in) a password will be required.

Comment: I still want to be able to sign in with the pin, just not use it as an admin password

Comment: No automatic way to do that so far as I know. Keep your PIN for yourself, do not give it out, then at login there is a selection for PIN, Password, Fingerprint (if one) and select it. That will work.